# About how to make xml file for html which is in local folder

Tags: html, xml, ip-address, traversal

I'm looking for its way to make xml.
Though I tried it by web services below, I couldn't.
sitemapxml.jp
https://www.xml-sitemaps.com

I inputed My ipadress like this.
Ex.) http://192.188.100.100/pdt/index.html 
↑It's not true address because I don't want to be attacked.

Do you have any idea to make xml file ?

Comment: Are you asking specifically how to create a **sitemap**, or an XML file in general? And are you trying to do this through a website (`xml-sitemaps.com`) or your own code?

Comment: @ObsidianAge yes.I'm asking how to create XML file in general. I tried it on xml-sitemaps.com by my IPadress(ipv4). But I couldn't.

Comment: XML files are not limited to sitemaps. You are asking how to create a sitemap.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Ok. I probably got these meaning. yes I want to make sitemaps.